# Local interpretation of an open immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme and $D$ be a closed principle subscheme, i.e. the ideal sheaf $\mathcal I_D$ that cuts out $D$ is locally a principal ideal.

The open complement $U=X\setminus D$ induces an open immersion $j: U \to X$ locally given by the localization of a generator of $\mathcal I_D$. In particular $j$ is affine.

How can we prove this local interpretation?
Thanks for your help.

**Edit**
Locally we assume $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ affine and we cover it $X= \cup_i D(f_i)$ by distinguished open subsets for $f_i \in A, \forall i$. Then

$j^{-1}(D(f_i)) = D(f_i) = Spec (A/f_i)$. So we can see that $j$ is indeed affine but the description of $j$ is not given in term of localization by a generator of and ideal $I_D$, locally corresponding to the ideal sheaf $\mathcal I_D$?

**Edit2**
If we consider $D=\operatorname{Spec}(A/I)$ locally given by the ideal $I=\langle f \rangle\subseteq A$, then $U = \{\mathfrak p\in X=\operatorname{Spec A}| f\not\in\mathfrak p \} = D(f)$.
Hence $j$ corresponds to the localization by $f$: $A \to A_f$.

Comment: For many people, the statement you've written would be sufficient proof. Can you say a little more about what you need help with?

Comment: Dear @KReiser, thank you, I just edited my question for more details on my issue.

Comment: Dear @KReiser, I added more details to my Edit2. Does it make sense?

Comment: Your edit 2 is basically the explanation I would give: cover $X$ by affine open sets $\operatorname{Spec} A$ where $\mathcal{I}_D$ is free, say generated by $f$, then on such an open set $j$ corresponds to $\operatorname{Spec}$ of the natural map $A\to A_f$, which fulfills the criteria for $f$ to be affine. (Edit 1 doesn't make a lot of sense - $D(f_i)$ is $\operatorname{Spec} A_{f_i}$, *not* $\operatorname{Spec} A/f_i$.)

Comment: Many thanks dear @KReiser for your help!
I would be happy to accept it if you write your comment as an answer.